# QGIS filters features of FileGDB by itself

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I have a `FileGDB` loaded into QGIS. In the layer properties under `information` - `information from provider`, `feature count` is 298. Under `source` there is **no** provider feature filter set. In the attribute table, there are only 283 features available. Also, when I export the feature or run a tool (e.g. check validity) there are only 283 features returned (in case of check validity 278 valid and 5 invalid).

Does anyone know, why there might be some features filtered by QGIS?

How can I access the filtered features or at least remove them of the `FileGDB` (I don’t want to export the Data to a new `FileGDB`, because there are several field domains set)?
[image: attribute table]

Comment: QGIS sometimes have issues with geometry-less records. See this [bug report](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/55065)